# Does a Toyota Corolla need liners for their rear wheel wells?

Tags: toyota, corolla

Does a 2016 Toyota Corolla LE come with liners for their rear wheel wells? Does it need them?

The front wheel wells have plastic liners but the rear wheel wells do not;

- There is a visible cable, more exposed than I would have expected.
- There is a little shelf which looks ideal for water/snow/salt to gather in this winter. (You can partially see this shelf at the very bottom in [this picture of the rear wheel well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca0OJ.jpg), where some pebbles have gathered.)

So should my car have come (as standard) with a liner/shield like in [this linked picture](http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b603/camrydaddy/re_cardboard_zps41c47172.jpg) (apparently of a 2012 Toyota Camry)?

If I am missing this liner, is it putting my car at risk of damage from stones or rust?

Comment: From the picture it doesn't look like it does. Take a look at the bottom of the panel and see if it has slots for plastic rivets or screws.

Comment: Usually most new cars do have liners in all four guards, some don't. While I'd *assume* you've just lost yours, you can check around the inside of the wheel well for vacant holes. That might give you a clue as to whether or not the liner is missing, or just not there to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To liner or not to liner, ahhh.  That is the question.

It's a bit of a crapshoot.  A well-designed liner will keep the debris off the important bits.

A not-well-designed liner will accumulate the nasties at an alarming rate.

Being a Subaru geek, I can tell you that Fuji Heavy Industries (Subaru) tried really hard to protect the fuel filler neck with some plastic shielding "liners".

Which ultimately made a nice cubby for all kinds of salt and dirt to rot out the filler neck.  It was a minor problem... only a few million cars.

I honestly wouldn't worry about it.  If you live in a salt-the-roads-during winter-area, get some extra car washes.